# c# change value of javascript variable from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a variable named "tempVariable" in my jquery file.
now I need to change its value from code behind in c#.
What I have done till now is

in my C# code

```
public void changeValueInJquery()
{
    bool newVal = false;
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
        GetType(), 
        "key", "ChangeValue(" + newVal + ");", true);
 }
```

my jquery code is as

```
function ChangeValue(value1) {
    alert(value1);
    tempVariable = value1;
}
```

The issue is that ChangeValue() function never gets hit.

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: have you had a look at the generated script in source view?

Comment: There is nothing jQuery in this question. `jQuery != Javascript`

Comment: Another option is just take hidden variable and take its value in jQuery. You can change its value from code behind..

Comment: jamiec: I have not posted my whole jquery file here.. The only function where I need changes is what is shown here..

Comment: You're solution may well contain jQuery, but nothing about this question has anything whatsoever to do with jQuery. My solution might have HTML, CSS, C#, javascript and jQuery. If I have a c# question I wouldnt tag it jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be `'...'` is required to pass value...

Try this :

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("changevalue", "<script>ChangeValue('" + newVal + "');</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check in a JS debugger to see if you are getting any errors.

But generally try using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript();` instead if you are calling functions already present in the page.  This will ensure that the script block is rendered at the bottom of the page and not for example before the ChangeValue function.

As other people have mentioned, this is nothing to do with jQuery.